# Anybody know of a backup location for: www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, database-backups, forum

This url:

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf

..has been on my browser bookmark bar for years....now the site is apparently down forever.

Does anyone know where a copy of that particular .nsf file might be?    I should have created a replica and never did.

HCL maybe?

Comment: This is referring to the Lotus Notes development forum. It is not asking for a recommendation, It is an appropriate question for this site. Please do not close.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related.

Comment: How can you say it’s not programming related when it was maybe the best resource for thousands of us when it was still up…and a resource for what? For,programming! It was our stackoverflow for lotus notes/domino for years, and succumbed to the sale to HCL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HCL says it’s working on putting notes.net back online https://support.hcltechsw.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=8b8716de1b9a001483cb86e9cd4bcb92. Until then you can use archived forum at http://web.archive.org/web/20190910022042/http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf but you will have trouble searching it.